# KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex ]are in the [columns] on pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, line-plot

Wondering why is not working with pandas lineplot?

```
N = 1000
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='D', periods=N)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'], index=rng)

df1.plot.line(x=df1.index,y=df1["A"])
```

And I got this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04',\n               '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-08',\n               '2000-01-09', '2000-01-10',\n               ...\n               '2002-09-17', '2002-09-18', '2002-09-19', '2002-09-20',\n               '2002-09-21', '2002-09-22', '2002-09-23', '2002-09-24',\n               '2002-09-25', '2002-09-26'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1000, freq=None)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: 1. There is no `z` defined in your code, 2. The syntax is `df1.plot.line(x='**columnname1**', y=**'column_name2'**)`. Do not pass the series into these arguments.

Comment: thank you , sorry the z was typo .changed to 'x=df1.index' steel not working works fine with "plt.plot(df1.index, df1["A"])" or sns.lineplot(x=df1.index,y=df1["A"]), i dnont know why it does not work with panfdas directly

Comment: *i dnont know why it does not work with panfdas directly* Because Pandas syntax is different. In Pandas `x` and `y` are **always column names**. It's simply `df1.plot.line(y='A')` or just `df1['A'].plot()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang has provided the correct answer, this should be closed